Fit token to dimension
I’m using Python with LangChain to transform .txt files into chunks, where each chunk contains 512 tokens.
Next, I generate embeddings for each chunk and insert them into Milvus. The embedding dimension is set to 512.
I initially thought that 1 token would correspond to 1 dimension, but this isn’t the case. Milvus requires the full dimensionality (512) for each vector. Because of this, I am forced to produce vectors with empty dimensions when the number of tokens doesn’t fully occupy the 512 dimensions, leading to errors or the need to generate filler.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to effectively utilize all dimensions without needing to resort to fillers? Ideally, I’d like to insert into Milvus without using all 512 dimensions, but the pymilvus library seems to require full dimensionality or it throws an error.
"Error processing text file: <MilvusException: (code=0, message=the length(5) of float data should divide the dim(512))>"


To generate embeddings, we use an embedding model. So basically we send a piece of text (chunk) as input to the embedding model (NOT a tokenizer, there's a huge difference), and the embedding model always returns a vector of FIXED dimension as an output.
The text input to the embedding model can range from a single word to the maximum token limit of the embedding model, but the output would remain CONSTANT. There is no correlation between the number of tokens in the input and the embedding size generated.
Just ensure that the embedding dimension of the vector database is set equal to the embedding dimensions of the vectors generated by the embedding model you use. For example, OpenAI embeddings would ALWAYS return embedding vectors of 1536. Hence to store those in a vector database, you need to set the embedding size in the vector database to 1536.
